# Get DIV index value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am stuck with a problem here, please help. What my requirement is to get the index value of the div clicked. Have 2 lists, and i need to call a function doSomething(); only when the user clicks the first div set. Is there anyway that i can achieve it.

The scripts and HTML is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".list-wrapper li").click(function() {
    var index = $(".list-wrapper div").index(this);
    alert(index);
    });
});

<div class="list-wrapper">
<ul>
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
<li>List 3</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="list-wrapper">
<ul>
<li>List 1</li>
<li>List 2</li>
<li>List 3</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has powerful [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), so usually you don't need to check the index after the event. For example:

For the first div on your page:

```
$(".list-wrapper:first").click(doSomething);
```

For the first `<li>`s in every list:

```
$(".list-wrapper li:first-child").click(doSomething);
```

If you still want to find the index, you need to search for the parent `div` of the clicked `li`. Also, the selector `.list-wrapper div` is empty - you don't have any `div`s in `list-wrapper`. This will work:

```
var parent = $(this).closest('div')
var index = $(".list-wrapper").index(parent);
```

Answer (score 1):

if it only needs to be on the first one use the :first selector

http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

```
$("div.list-wrapper:first").find("li").click(function() {...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this:

```
$('div.list-wrapper').first().click(function() { doSomething(); });
```

and

```
$("div.list-wrapper:first").click(function() { doSomething(); });
```

and

```
$('div.list-wrapper').eq(0).click(function() { doSomething(); });
```

are the first ones that come to mind. Pro-tip, include the element type before the class for speed (div.blah faster than .blah)

Or to just get the index:

```
var index = $('div.list-wrapper').index(this);
```

replace 'this' with the parent for specificity

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
<ul><li id="foo">foo</li><li id="bar">bar</li><li id="baz">baz</li></ul>


var listItem = document.getElementById('bar');
alert('Index: ' + $('li').index(listItem));
```

See this for more info :
http://api.jquery.com/index/